# How to write test for page Controller?

Tags: apex

This is controller:

public class ProductTablePageController {

public List getProducts() {

```
List<Product__c> results = Database.query(
   'SELECT Id, Name,  UnitPrice__c, UnitsAvailable__c, Description__c, AddedDate__c, ImageURL__c ' +
   'FROM Product__c ' +
   'ORDER BY AddedDate__c desc');
return results;
```

}

```
}
```

Here is test

@isTest
public class TestProductApplication {

```
public class ProductTablePageController {

     static  testMethod void getProductsTest(){
     Product__c newpr =  new Product__c();
    newpr.Name = 'max';
     newpr.UnitPrice__c = 2;
         insert newpr;
        Product__c resultpr = [SELECT Id, Name, UnitPrice__c FROM Product__c  ];
        System.assertEquals('max', resultpr.Name);
System.assertEquals(2, resultpr.UnitPrice__c);

     }   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an Instance of the controller with the *new* keyword then call its methods like you would any other class. This will cause the code to execute in a test execution and therefore pass apex tests. I'm not sure if you're using the product you insert as a record to check the method against but you could get rid of that if you want.

```
@isTest public class TestProductApplication {

    static  testMethod void getProductsTest(){
    Product__c newpr =  new Product__c();
    newpr.Name = 'max';
    newpr.UnitPrice__c = 2;
    insert newpr;
    Product__c resultpr = [SELECT Id, Name, UnitPrice__c FROM Product__c  ];
    System.assertEquals('max', resultpr.Name);
    System.assertEquals(2, resultpr.UnitPrice__c);

    //Initialize the controller
    ProductTablePageController ctr = new ProductTablePageController(); 
    List<Product__c> retrndProds = ctr.getProducts(); //Call method and get products
    System.assert(retrndProds.size() > 0); //Run assertions on the list
    Product__c listProd = retrndProds[0];
    System.assert(listProd == resultpr); //Some more checks on the list
    }
}
```

Hope this helps